# Format error while exporting to excel from gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I Tried a few solutions mentioned in the site like `Using System.Microsoft.Office.Excel` and `Excel =  System.Microsoft.Office.Excel`, but it dint work.... 
Here, I'm trying to get the data in a table and download to a file in the specified location in the server in .xls format and then giving the users a link to download the file.
this is the code for export `

```
protected void btnExcelExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        using( HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            //  Create a form to contain the grid
            Table table = new Table();
            // get gridlines from gridview
            table.GridLines = GridView2.GridLines;
            if (GridView2.HeaderRow != null)
            {                       
                table.Rows.Add(GridView2.HeaderRow);
            }
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            if (GridView2.FooterRow != null)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(GridView2.FooterRow);
            }    
            //  render the table into the htmlwriter
            table.RenderControl(htw);    
        }
        var myRootPath = Server.MapPath("~");
        var docPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(myRootPath, "/Compare/c.xls")); 
        File.WriteAllText(docPath, sw.ToString());  
    }
    dwndlink.Visible = true;

}
```

And when this is code for linkbutton:

```
 protected void dwnlink(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {   
     var webRootPath = Server.MapPath("~");
     var docPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(webRootPath, "/Compare/c.xls"));

     string name = Path.GetFileName(docPath);
     Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
     Response.ContentType = "Application/vnd.ms-excel";
     Response.TransmitFile(docPath);
     Response.End();
 }
```

so when the user opens the downloaded file, gives a warning as its not in the same extension.
Why is this happening..??

I tried working with the solutions provided in various sites, but to no avail...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";` to `Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"`

Also

Microsoft document says :

"The current design does not allow you to open HTML content from a web site in Excel... So ASP pages that return HTML and set the MIME type to something like XLS to try to force the HTML to open in Excel instead of the web browser (as expected) will always get the security alert... If you use an HTML MIME type, then the web browser will open the content instead of Excel. So there is no good workaround for this case because of the lack of a special MIME type for HTML/MHTML that is Excel specific. You can add your own MIME type if you control both the web server and the client desktops that need access to it, but otherwise the best option is to use a different file format or alert your users of the warning and tell them to select Yes to the dialog."

Visit this site too : http://devblog.grinn.net/2008/06/file-you-are-trying-to-open-is-in.html

Comment: tried vid vnd-ms-excel...but the issue....:(
edit: is there no plausible workaround to this issue, i mean i used up all the MIME types given in msdn....but, the issue isnt ready to vanish...thanks